Crear control de usuario personalizado
Estoy creando una aplicación en Visual Studio. Quiero crear un control de usuario textbox personalizado, el cual cuando recibe el foco cambia el color backgroound y cuando lo pierde lo vuelve a cambiar, a parte de otras opciones que tengo.
El tema es que ese mismo textbox quiero que lea los datos desde una consulta SQL y no hay forma, si lo hago con un texbox normal si que puede leer los datos, pero desde el mio no.
El codigo de mi textbox es el siguiente:
Public Class txtTextBox

    Public Property MaxLength As Integer
    Public Property UseSystemPasswordChar As Boolean

    Private Sub txtValue_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtValue.GotFocus
        txtValue.BackColor = Color.LightCyan
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtValue_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtValue.LostFocus
        txtValue.BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub
End Classs

¿Debo poner algo más para que me funcione la funcion LostFocus en la clase y en el formulario? ¿O no se puede?
La última vez que programé era con vb 6 y todo esto me vuelve un poco loco, aunque me voy defendiendo y sacando cositas adelante.
Gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Cual es el problema?? el foco? o algo de la base de datos? me perdi sobre cual es tu problema.. otra cosa... wpf?? winforms?? maui???

Creo que el control debería heredar de TextBox y, de hecho, si solo vas a cambiar el comportamiento al recibir o perder foco, bastaría con asignar eventos en lugar de crear un nuevo control.

ya lo tengo resuelto, al crear el Control Windows forms lo estaba haciendo mal, realmente tenia que crear un componente, al cual le he creado propiedades para poder hacer más cosas con él.
 Imports System.CodeDom Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    
    Public Class txtTexbox
        Inherits TextBox
    
        Private GetFocus As Color = Color.LightCyan
        Private _SoloNumeros As Boolean
        Private _Email As Boolean
    
        'CAMBIA DE COLOR EN EL EVENTO GOT Y LOST FOCUS
        Public Property ColorFoco() As Color
            Get
                ColorFoco = GetFocus
            End Get
            Set(value As Color)
                GetFocus = value
            End Set
        End Property
    
        Private Sub TomarFoco(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
            Me.BackColor = ColorFoco
        End Sub
        Private Sub PerderFoco(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
            Me.BackColor = Color.White
        End Sub

Ahora si que puedo ejecutar el código sin problemas y creando solo un componente hacer que tengas varias opciones (Email, password, solonumeros, gotfocus, etc)
Gracias
